# Chiddushei Rav Chaim Halevi Hilkhot Gerushin 6:9

Tags: divorce

Below is a section from Chiddushei Rav Chaim. In the last paragraph, Rav Chaim gives an answer to his initial question as to why Rambam connected the reason why a קטנה cannot appoint a שליח לקבלה to an issue of עדות. I am having trouble understanding how he explains this connection in a way that answers the question. Could someone try to explain it to me?

חידושי ר' חיים הלוי הלכות גירושין פרק ו
[ט] וקטנה אינה עושה שליח לקבלה אעפ"י שחצרה קונה לה גיטה כגדולה מפני ששליח קבלה צריך עדים ואין מעידין על הקטן שאינו בן דעה גמורה עכ"ל.

ובהשגות חולק על טעם זה ומסיים ז"ל אלא אתם גם אתם לרבות שלוחכם מה אתם בני דעת אף שלוחכם בני דעת נמצא שהשליח והשולח צריכין להיות בני דעת עכ"ל, ובפ"ב מה' שלוחין ושותפין כתב הרמב"ם ז"ל אבל מי שאינם בני דעת והם חרש שוטה וקטן אינן נעשין שלוחין ולא עושים שליח אחד הקטן ואחד הקטנה עכ"ל, הרי דכן היא גם דעת הרמב"ם בעצמו ג"כ, וכמבואר כן בכמה דוכתין בש"ס, וצ"ע א"כ מה הוצרך בכאן להוסיף עוד טעם לפי שאין מעידין על הקטן, וצ"ע.

והנה ביבמות דף קי"ח ע"ב איבעיא המזכה גט לאשתו במקום יבם מהו כיון דסניא ליה זכות הוא לה וזכין לאדם שלא בפניו, או דילמא כיון דזימנין דרחמא ליה חוב הוא לה ואין חבין לאדם שלא בפניו, ושוב שם המזכה גט לאשתו במקום קטטה מהו כיון דאית לה קטטה בהדיה זכות הוא לה או דילמא ניחא דגופא עדיף לה וכו', הרי דבמקום זכות יכול לזכות גט לאשתו גם שלא בפניה ורק דהאיבעיא היא אם הוא זכות או חוב, ובמקום יבם נשאר בספיקא דהוי ספק זכות. וצ"ע מה דינו בקטנה כה"ג, דהרי קי"ל דזכין לקטן בכל מקום ומשום דכיון דאמרינן זכין לאדם שלא בפניו א"כ הא קטן וגדול שוין ונעשין שליח עבורו שלא מדעתו, ולדעת הרבה מהראשונים הוא דין תורה אף לקטן, וא"כ בגט כה"ג צ"ע מה דינו בקטנה, כיון דאמרינן זכין לקטן ונעשין שליח עבורו מדין תורה, א"כ יכולין לקבל גם גט זה דהוי זכות לה עבורה, או דמ"מ לא מהניא בקטנה, וצ"ע.

ונראה דמשום הכי הוסיף הרמב"ם הך טעמא דאין מעידין על הקטן, דהרי משום הך טעמא דבעינן בני דעת הרי היתה יכולה לקבל גט ע"י שליח במקום שהגט הוא זכות לה, אבל משום הך טעמא דאין מעידין על הקטן אינו מועיל מה דהוי זכות לה, כיון דמ"מ עדים מיהא בעינן, דשליחות גט צריך עדים, ואין מעידין על הקטן, וע"כ לא מהניא אף במקום שזכות הוא לה.

Comment: He is saying that there is a case where the shlichus can be done without the regular dinei shlichus, if it is a zechus for her, and therefore it would not need the regular din of bar daas for the meshalaich and shliach. However, the Ramabm adds in the reason of eidus to include even such a case of zechus which might work in other instances, but not by a Get since it needs eidim and that cannot be done for a katana.

Comment: @Chatzkel As opposed to a שליח להבאה, that doesn't require *eidim* according to the Rambam (*Hil. Geirushin* 6:4). | Somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48860

Comment: I see. So, one way of putting it is that the Rambam's insertion reflects the centrality of עדות in גט to the extent that the requirement of עדות prevents us from employing זכין לאדם שלא בפניו. @Fred, I guess the question then becomes why the difference between שליחות להבאה vs לקבלה? Maybe קבלת הגט is somehow more privileged than שליחות הגט in the חלות גירושין. Thanks!

Comment: *Daas* implies the ability to do something. In *kabalas ha'get* the woman is entirely passive and merely has to present her *reshus*. Therefore her *minuy shliach* is not "doing something", it is an extension of her *reshus* only. Therefore the fact that she is not a *bar daas* and a *bar peulah* is irrelevant.